# Mail & Calendar App for Windows 8.1

Tags: 8.1, apps, outlook, side-loading

I need to run this app - https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/mail-and-calendar/9wzdncrfhvqm on a Lumia 525 running Windows 8.1

Is there a way to download the package and sideload it to the phone?

I know it may not work - but I want to at least try it.

It's sad that we have an Outlook App which runs on older Androids & Apple phones but not on a Lumia.

Comment: You **can not** sideload Windows 10 Mobile app in Windows phone  8.1, and there's no way to download package other than Store.

Comment: What do you need the new app for? The Mail and Calendar apps on WP8.1 are perhaps not quite so advanced as on W10M, but they do the job pretty well and support the same kinds of accounts. In fact, I prefer the older Calendar app's UI. 
Alternatively, you could install W10M on your Lumia 525. It's not officially supported and will run a bit slowly, but it does work. I've got an old 520 (used as a test device) that runs W10M well enough.

Comment: @CBHacking - the 8.1 Mail app doesn't support the use case where the  Exchange server is integrated with some 3rd party RADIUS Server for 2 factor authentication

Comment: @CBHacking - how do I install W10M on the 525?

Comment: @user93353 That's a question in its own right, but the short version is [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-dht-upgrade-advisor-redstone-lumias-t3434774). Basically you edit the phone's registry (using a tool) to report the phone as being a different model to the update server, take an update that's just the OS bits (no drivers, as they won't match your hardware), and then restore the correct registry data. Coming from WP8.1, you *might* need an SD card, and the full process may be a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to run a W10 app in WP 8.1.

This is true even for Android. An app made with the new versions of Android cannot run on older version. However developers target Kitkat to cover majority of users. In case of Windows W10 has more users than WP8. 1 and it has more advanced APIs. So development will be going forward for Windows 10. It is best to switch to a new mobile with Windows 10.

Comment: ` It is best to switch to a new mobile with Windows 10.` Only a moron will buy a Windows Phone anymore. If even Microsoft doesn't provide an app for their older versions of the phone, why would anyone buy another Microsoft OS phone.